# Excel to dataset but some data is null

Tags: c#

Excel to dataset in convert then if excel in first 10th rows int and after rows is string then output is string value is null so how to handle all column as text datatype and string value is not null get

i also use connection string in
Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Format=xls;ImportMixedTypes=TEXT;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0